# Azure bot channels not connecting to bot

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service

I have created a bot and am able to test it in the Bot Emulator. I am also able to POST a call to the hosted (Azure) bot through the REST API (Postman), as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-4.0), and it works correctly.

The bot has two channels added: Web Chat which I guess is there by default and Skype which I added and configured myself.

Neither of these channels send messages to the bot.

Web Chat produces "Issues" with the message `There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code Unauthorized` whereas Skype does not report any "Issues" but also doesn't do anything.

How is it that channels added through the Azure portal are not able to access the bot?

If Web Chat is "Unauthorized", how on earth do I authorize it?

Comment: Did you try sending a message from the "Test in web chat" from azure itself?
Also have you published any new code to the service?

Comment: Yes, that is where the errors are coming from "Test in web chat". Yes, I have a working web app that I have tested in the emulator and it works in the cloud from the REST API

Comment: Can you simply restart your app service from portal and try again?

Comment: I tried restarting the app service and get the same result

Comment: It seems that the issue is that authentication is required by the App Service, wheich is not what I need for now. I just can't find a way to disable it. This post https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorisation that it can be done but doesn't say how.

Comment: Maybe you could check if your app is registered in your AAD

Comment: There is an option to configure diagnostic settings on the bot from Azure portal. This can log all requests to storage or other available options. This should provide more details about the error since the test in webchat itself seems to fail.